# how to sort an array of objects with different keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to sort an array of objects by a key in a particular position. The only problem is that each object has a different key name.

here is an example of an object i'm trying to sort:

```
let data = [
  {name: "James", x: 3, }, 
  {name: "Thomas", y: 1}, 
  {name: "Zack", z: 2}
];
```

I'm trying to sort it by the 2nd key so the order should be

```
    [
      {name: "James", x: 3, }, 
      {name: "Zack", z: 2},
      {name: "Thomas", y: 1} 
    ];
```

here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
let data = [
      {name: "James", x: 3, }, 
      {name: "Thomas", y: 1}, 
      {name: "Zack", z: 2}
    ];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  let key1 = Object.keys(a)[1];
  let key2 = Object.keys(b)[1];
  return a[key1] > b[key2]
  });
console.log(data)
```

Here is my jsbin

https://jsbin.com/lihefodoni/edit?html,js,console

Not sure why it's not working. I'm trying to do this in my react Application so I don't know if there's something different I need to do?

Comment: Urgh. There is no such thing as "the second key". Key value pairs in objects are not really ordered.

Comment: don't objects in javascript retain their order? @JonasWilms

Comment: To hammer @JonasWilms point home. The [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) documentation says: *"in the same order as we get with a normal loop."*. Moving on to the [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Description) documentation: *"A `for...in` loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order (see the `delete` operator for more on why one cannot depend on the seeming orderliness of iteration, at least in a cross-browser setting)."*

Comment: In ES6+ environments, yes, order is preserved, but it's not guaranteed in ES5. Best not to rely on it

Comment: @james well they do. Object keys are ordered *by insertion time*. That means that if you do `delete data[0].name; data[0].name = "test";` then you change the order of the keys. And someone might do that with your dataset. And in that moment your code will fail. And someone will have to find out why it failed and that person will spend days to find the small design mistake you are making right now. It'll work, maybe today, maybe for a year, but somewhen it'll fail.

Comment: If the creation of the objects is under your control, you can simply add a third property that holds the key that needs to be sorted. You can also use this property to access the value of the dynamic key. `obj = { name: "James", x: 3, pointer: "x" }` This allows you to order by the value of `obj.pointer` and allows you to dynamically access the attribute value by doing `obj[obj.pointer]`

Comment: @JonasWilms—where is your reference for the assertion that "*Object keys are ordered by insertion time*"? There are certain objects that maintain an order (e.g. [*Map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-map.prototype.foreach)), but it's not a general requirement of Objects as far as I can see in ECMA-262.

Comment: @robG its in 9.1.11.1 `For each own property key P of O that is a String but is not an integer index, in ascending chronological order
of property creation, do ...`. That operation gets called by `for...in` and others.

Comment: @JonasWilms—Thanks. E.g. *Object.keys* uses *EnumerableOwnPropertyNames*, which returns a *List* that must be in the same order as *EnumerateObjectProperties* would generate. That calls `[[OwnPropertyKeys]]`, which uses [*OrdinaryOwnPropertyKeys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys), which seems to have been added to ECMAScript 2017.

Comment: @robG yup, the authors of the spec should really focus more on understandability :)

Comment: @JonasWilms—specifications are hard to write, I think they're doing an OK job. I wish they'd include references for when particular features or parts are added. That way I don't have to go hunting through old specs to find when they've changed. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.sort` callback expects a *number* as a return value, not a Boolean (as the `<` operator will evaluate to). Return the numeric difference instead:

```js
let data = [
      {name: "James", x: 3, }, 
      {name: "Thomas", y: 1}, 
      {name: "Zack", z: 2}
    ];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  let key1 = Object.keys(a)[1];
  let key2 = Object.keys(b)[1];
  return b[key2] - a[key1]
});
console.log(data)
```

To make sorting more reliable, `.find` the entry whose key is not `name`:

```js
let data = [
      {name: "James", x: 3, }, 
      {name: "Thomas", y: 1}, 
      {name: "Zack", z: 2}
    ];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  const aEntry = Object.entries(a).find(([key]) => key !== 'name');
  const bEntry = Object.entries(b).find(([key]) => key !== 'name');
  return bEntry[1] - aEntry[1];
});
console.log(data)
```

Comment: thanks! but i'm wondering why something like this works then?
data = [{x: 1}, {x: 3} ,{x: 2}];

data.sort((a, b) => {
  return a.x > b.x
  });

Comment: Because you have to tell `.sort` about three different cases. `a` is before `b`, `b` is before `a`, and `a` and ` b` are the same. A Boolean can only represent two states: true or false, it cannot represent three states. Returning a boolean will never work reliably. Your example works by accident, shuffling the array would also result in the right result sometimes.

Comment: @james It doesn't: https://jsfiddle.net/w72bucdp/ `0: {x: 1}
1: {x: 3}
2: {x: 2}`

Comment: huh that's so weird. it works fine in the javascript repl website but fails on jsfiddle @Snow

Comment: Thats not weird. If you change the engine, the implementation changes. If you use the API in an unspecified way, then you get unspecified results.

Comment: Specifically, repl.it looks to be running the code on node v10.15.2 linux/amd64, which is not the same as in Chrome (or FF, etc). The output is implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the unwanted key and take the values of the object. it works by taking the only item without index.

```js
let data = [{ name: "James", x: 3 }, { name: "Thomas", y: 1 }, { name: "Zack", z: 2 }];

data.sort(({ name, ...a }, { name: _, ...b }) => Object.values(b) - Object.values(a));

console.log(data)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```